# Qt not rendering alpha channel to platform plugin

Tags: c++, qt

I have a very simple app the renders a transparent widget with half opacity. Everything works with the default environment platform (X11, etc).

```
class TestWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    TestWidget(QWidget* parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        this->setWindowOpacity(.5);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    TestWidget widget;

    QCheckBox* checkBox = new QCheckBox(&widget);
          checkBox->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("checkBox"));
          checkBox->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 89, 20));

    widget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 240, 320));

    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

This works as expected.

However, if use a custom platform plugin that I developed (based off of the minimal example), the rendered image has no alpha layer.

**NOTE:** *It turns out that the minimal platform in qt does this also, but just in case, I will show my platform code also.*

Here is the platform screen.

```
QEncirisPlatformScreen::QEncirisPlatformScreen()
    : mDepth(32),
      mFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied),
      mGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 240, 320))
{

}

QEncirisPlatformScreen::~QEncirisPlatformScreen()
{

}

QRect QEncirisPlatformScreen::geometry() const
{
    return mGeometry;
}

int QEncirisPlatformScreen::depth() const
{
    return mDepth;
}

QImage::Format QEncirisPlatformScreen::format() const
{
    return mFormat;
}
```

And here is the backing store.

```
QEncirisPlatformBackingStore::QEncirisPlatformBackingStore(QWindow *window)
    : QPlatformBackingStore(window)
    , mDebug(QEncirisPlatformIntegration::instance()->options() & QEncirisPlatformIntegration::DebugBackingStore)
{
    if (mDebug)
        qDebug() << "QMinimalBackingStore::QMinimalBackingStore:" << (quintptr)this;
    mImage = new QImage(window->size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    mImage->fill(Qt::transparent);
}

QEncirisPlatformBackingStore::~QEncirisPlatformBackingStore()
{
}

QPaintDevice *QEncirisPlatformBackingStore::paintDevice()
{
    if (mDebug)
        qDebug() << "QMinimalBackingStore::paintDevice";

    return &(*mImage);
}

void QEncirisPlatformBackingStore::flush(QWindow *window, const QRegion &region, const QPoint &offset)
{
    Q_UNUSED(window);
    Q_UNUSED(region);
    Q_UNUSED(offset);

    if (mDebug)
    {
        static int c = 0;
        QString filename = QString("output%1.png").arg(c++, 4, 10, QLatin1Char('0'));
        qDebug() << "QMinimalBackingStore::flush() saving contents to" << filename.toLocal8Bit().constData();
        mImage->save(filename);

        // this is false
        qDebug() << "Has alpha " << mImage->data_ptr()->checkForAlphaPixels();
    }
}

void QEncirisPlatformBackingStore::resize(const QSize &size, const QRegion &)
{
    QImage::Format format = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->handle()->format();
    if (mImage->size() != size)
        mImage = new QImage(size, format);
}
```

This images saved to the files system display the correct widgets, but there is no alpha transparency. The background seems to be the color #efebe7 (tan), which I do not set anywhere.

How do I get my backing store to have an `mImage` that contains the alpha/opacity?